# Verilog syntax error after if control statement

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, verilog

I am trying to make a zero check module in Verilog for my several different select modules.

```
module check_zero (input [63:0] a, b, [1:0] select, output reg [63:0] out);

if ((a[51:0] == 0) && (b[51:0] == 0)) begin  
          out <= 0;
          state <= done;

end else if (a[51:0]==0 && select==0) begin
      out <= b;
          state <= done;
end else if (b[51:0]==0 && select==0) begin
      out <= a;
          state <= done;

end else if (a[51:0]==0 && select==1) begin
      out[63] <= ~b[63];
      out[62:0] <= ~b[62:0];
          state <= done;
end else if (b[51:0]==0 && select==1) begin
      out <= a;
          state <= done;

end else if (a[51:0]==0 && select==2) begin
      out <= 0;
          state <= done;
end else if (b[51:0]==0 && select==2) begin
      out <= 0;
          state <= done;
end

end else if (a[51:0]==0 && select==3) begin
      out <= 0;
          state <= done;
end else if (b[51:0]==0 && select==3) begin
        out[63] <= 1;
            out[62:52] <= 2047;
            out[51] <= 1;
            out[50:0] <= 0;
            state <= done;
end
endmodule
```

I am getting 2 errors in Modelsim:
 1. (vlog-13069) syntax error, unexpected '<=' in line 2 after out
 2. (vlog-13205) syntax error found in the scope following out, is there a missing '::'

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra "end" there.

```
 end else if (b[51:0]==0 && select==2) begin
 out <= 0;
 state <= done;
 end // this is extra, delete it
```

Comment: Also missing an `always @*`